# Xamarin UITest native IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsU8vg1_g0s) I found is to UITest android APK file in Xamarin.

But I have an IOS app written using XCode IDE. And I would like to use Xamarin UITest to test my IOS app.

How can I UITest my IOS app from Xamarin? Can XCode IDE generate a package similar to Android? So that I can test it in Xamarin?

Comment: You will need to link in the calabash.framework into your IOS app: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#step-1-link-calabashframework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITest is based on the calabash project, here is the IOS repo and some guidance: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios

Comment: how about this reference (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/selecting-ios-simulator/) ? If I follow this guide, do I need to use Calabash project?

Comment: You will need the Calabash-ios library to allow *either UITest (c#), or Calabash (Ruby) test code to be able to automate your app's UI.  The link you sent only refers to a small slice of the setup necessary on the Test project side.  You also need to enable your project-to-be-tested to _accept_ the automation, and that's what the calabash-ios library does.